# Issue executing studentT in PyMC3

Tags: theano, pymc3

I try to execute StudentT() but receive error . Error is

> "ImportError: ('DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.', '[Elemwise{log1p,no_inplace}()]')"

If I use Normal(), there is no issue.

```
from pymc3 import StudentT
with pm.Model() as model:
        pm.glm.glm('Returns ~ AAP+CTXS+CAH+LLL', data,
        family=glm.families.StudentT())
        start = pm.find_MAP()
        step = pm.NUTS(scaling=start)
        trace = pm.sample(2000, step, start=start)
```

Comment: Update your question instead of adding comment

Comment: Something went wrong with your Theano installation on your Windows machine. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34508431/installing-theano-on-windows-dll-load-failed) for more details. If you have not tried it yet, try using Anaconda Python Distribution and ensure you are installing PyMC3 together with the developmental version of Theano as indicated [here](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/#installation)

Comment: @aloctavodia Thank you